# ElasticSearch cache update

Tags: java, jdbc, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

I have connected to a database with elastic jdbc river plugin and the elasticsearch has successfully indexed. If I change the value of the existing field will it be reflected in the index? For example I have a column called disabled and it may have 'y' or 'n' and at the start it has 'y' and get indexed. If I change it to 'n' later will it reflect it in the index and cache?

I have configured the river as scheduling for every 5 minutes. If it so, how it detects the update not the new insertion?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the query you're using to pull from your SQL database. If you're doing a general "select * from my_table" then you will get updates every 5 minutes but those updates may in fact create new items in Elasticsearch. Whether it creates the new or overwrites the old depends on mapping something you can use as an id in your SQL store as an  "_id" column. So to always update the elasticsearch data the query would then become "select my_id_field as _id,* from my_table"

Essentially the river doesn't do any detection of what was there before and what's there now. It's just taking your query and putting it in elasticsearch (it doesn't have a memory) and it will assign an _id field if you don't give it one.

You can give it one by making an es_track table and just doing incremental updates (typically based on time). The downside is that it may also require schema changes in that you need an "updated_at" type field in the table you're pulling from.